# How to plot a single datapoint with mean and standard deviation from a data frame in R

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

I have a large dataframe in R with this format:

```
"SubjID"    "HR"    "IBI"   "Stimulus"  "Status"
"S1"    75.98   790 1   1
"S1"    75.95   791 1   2
"S1"    65.7    918 1   3
"S1"    59.63   100 1   4
"S1"    59.44   101 1   5
"S1"    59.62   101 2   1
"S1"    63.85   943 2   2
"S1"    60.75   992 2   3
"S1"    59.62   101 2   4
"S1"    61.68   974 2   5
"S2"    65.21   921 1   1
"S2"    59.23   101 1   2
"S2"    61.23   979 1   3
"S2"    70.8    849 1   4
"S2"    74.21   809 1   4
```

I would like to plot the mean of the "HR" column for each one of the values of the status column.

I wrote the following R code where I create a subset of the data (by different values of "Status") and plot it:

```
numberOfSeconds <- 8;

    for(stimNumber in 1:40) {

    stimulus2plot <- subset(resampledDataFile, Stimulus == stimNumber & Status <= numberOfSeconds, select=c(SubjID, HR, IBI, Stimulus, Status))

    plot(stimulus2plot$HR~stimulus2plot$Status, xlab="",ylab="")
    lines(stimulus2plot$HR~stimulus2plot$Status, xlab="",ylab="")

    }
```

Thus obtaining a plot similar to the following:[image]

I have one plot per each "Stimulus". On the X axis of each plot I have the "Status" column, on the Y I have one "HR" value for each "SubjID". Almost there...

However what I would like to obtain ultimately is a single Y datapoint per each X value. i.e. Y should be the mean value (mean of HR column), similar to the following plot:

[image]

How can this be achieved? It would be great having also the standard deviation shown as error bars in each datapoint.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do it would be `tapply()`. If your `data.frame` is `data`:

```
means <- with(data, tapply(HR, Status, mean))
plot(means, type="l")
```

It is easy to calculate and plot the error bars as well:

```
serr <- with(data, tapply(HR, Status, function(x)sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))))
plot(means, type="o", ylim=c(50,80))
sapply(1:length(serr), function(i) lines(rep(i,2), c(means[i]+serr[i], means[i]-serr[i])))
```

Comment: thanks the first part works perfectly. If I use the second part of the code for the error bars however, the plot becomes a lot more "flat" (the lines are almost horizontal), while with just the mean you can see they vary in steepness

Comment: @Albz You just have to adjust the `ylim` argument, which specifies the lower and upper limits of the y-axis. I set it to `c(50,80)` so that the error bars could neatly fit in the plot, but you can adjust it to your pleasure. See `?plot.default`

Answer (score 2):

Easiest what you can do is first precompute the values, and then plot them. I would use `ddply` for this kind of analysis:

```
library(plyr)
res = ddply(df, .(Status), summarise, mn = mean(HR))
```

and plot it using ggplot2:

```
ggplot(res, aes(x = Status, y = mn)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

Comment: Edit my answer to reflect this bug.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll delete my comments in a view minutes, if you do the same than no record will exist of this bug other than my edit.

Answer (score 2):

To get it closest to what you want:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
df.summary <- ddply(df, .(Stimulus, Status), summarise,
                    HR.mean = mean(HR),
                    HR.sd = sd(HR))
ggplot(df.summary, aes(Status, HR.mean)) + geom_path() + geom_point() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=HR.mean-HR.sd, ymax=HR.mean+HR.sd), width=0.25) +facet_wrap(~Stimulus)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this completely within ggplot2 as follows, using the following fake data example as a guide:

```
DF <- data.frame(stimulus = factor(rep(paste("Stimulus", seq(4)), each = 40)),
                 subject = factor(rep(seq(20), each = 8)),
                 time = rep(seq(8), 20),
                 resp = rnorm(160, 50, 10))
# spaghetti plots
ggplot(DF, aes(x = time, y = resp, group = subject)) +
   geom_line() +
   facet_wrap(~ stimulus, ncol = 1)
# plot of time averages by stimulus
ggplot(DF, aes(x = time, y = resp)) +
   stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line", group = 1) +
   stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", group = 1, shape = 1) +
   facet_wrap(~ stimulus, ncol = 1)
```