# R: visualization of numeric value change in time per several categories, all IDs in the same plot - 3D plot?

Tags: r, plot, time-series

In R, I would like to make an aesthetically pleasing visualization of the following data (modification of time series):

```
    User ID | Date | Numeric_value | Category
    -----------------------------------------
```

I would like to plot a change of a numeric value daily for different users in the same graph, in each of the categories. That is we split this original data to observe numeric value change in each of the categories per user daily. Looks like 3-dimensional plot.

Data specifics: there are 50 different categories in data. User has numeric value in 1-5 categories at a time, and overtime this subset of categories for a user changes. We want to observe level of numeric values in these categories per user, how it cycles, when new categories per user appear and disappear and with what numeric value level.

The number of users goes in 10000s. Dates period is about 100 days.

Same User ID does not necessary appear every day with values in at least one category, while on the other day this User ID might have values in several categories. If I plot an individual, for example, I want every day to be shown, even if there is no value in any of categories. I guess, when I deal with many User IDs I will have values and categories on every day.

I can consider simplifying the task, producing separate graphs. Naturally, it suggests different graphs by category (like example provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360380/how-to-plot-a-single-datapoint-with-mean-and-standard-deviation-from-a-data-fram)), but I would not want that, because it is important to see a set of categories and respective values per user together.

I am not a pro with R, but considering data size, it also has to be a tool that can handle that size. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: I don't understand how you can realistically discern anything at the level of detail you want for 10K+ users.  I think you have to look at summary statistics at the category level (how many users or sum of value, etc.).

Comment: Agree with @BrodieG you'll have to find a useful way to group users. Maybe segmentation (try kmeans as an easy go to) followed by a presentation of summary statistics by segment by category?

Comment: Can you post a link to a representative sample of your data, say a few thousand rows?

Comment: The entire purpose of this visualization is to group users. Time series clustering is not an easy task, that is why I want to visualize first.